# jquery lazy load for dynamically loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

plugin i am using now :
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

I want to use lazy load for dynamically loaded content.
i.e content loaded using

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: postdata,
        success:function(data) {
                    $('#somediv').html(data);
                     //Do lazy loading now.
                    }
                })
```

Lazy load initilization

```
$("img.lazy").show().lazyload();
```

Comment: If I understand your question properly then the images won't load anyway until your 'success' handler executes. The browser will only request the images (lazy load?) when $('#somediv').html(data); executes.

Comment: And so what? You tried something?

Comment: i am loading content using jquery ajax, i want to append lazy load to those images loaded using ajax.

Comment: But `success` won't be called until all the content in the ajax call has been loaded anyway ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    $("img.lazy").lazyload({ 
        effect: "fadeIn" 
    }).removeClass("lazy");
});
```

Comment: some explanation would help this answer

Comment: ajaxStop checks whether the request has been finish, then it will trigger lazyload for the content that has been returned.

Comment: even if I write this in response method, it does not show images unless i scroll once. however this so far looks the possible solution

Comment: I am also seeing similar results to @asm234 . I have images loaded into a scroller and the first page of images load just fine however the 2nd half don't and have their src set to something like "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAANSURBVBhXYzh8+PB/AAffA0nNPuCLAAAAAElFTrSuQmCC". As soon as I scroll a tiny bit they load in correctly. Perhaps this is actually a bug in the LazyLoad script rather than the solution offered here?

Comment: Triggering the scroll event on various actions of the scroller my content was in forced the images to load. As an exampl, I was triggering a scroll using $(window).trigger("scroll")

Comment: @ProNotion above answer works for me. it basically needs to be done in the response of ajax request. CAUTION: do not use ajaxStop if you have multiple ajax calls on same page, simply put the code into the response call.